# Addition law of the tilt $K^\flat$ of a field $K$

Tags: field-theory, modular-arithmetic

This is an elementary question on the definition of the addition law of $K^\flat$, the tilt of an algebraically closed completely valued field $K$.

I am trying to follow [the excellent lectures notes of Lurie](https://www.math.ias.edu/%7Elurie/205.html). In lecture 1 the addition law is decribed briefly in proposition 5 on page 2. Then it is worked out in lecture 2, in remark 8.

But there, isn't there a typo in the sentence "so that $x_m + y_m \equiv z_m \pmod{p}$ for each $n\geq 0$." ? Isn't meant "for each $m$" ?  How is one meant to understand the calculation at the bottom of that page?

Also, on page 3 the limit is a way of writing an infinite sequence, is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your first question, yes -- this should say "$x_m + y_m\equiv z_m\pmod{p}$ for each $m\geq 0.$" I'm not sure exactly what you mean when you ask "how is one meant to understand the calculation at the bottom of that page?" Is there still something about the calculation that confuses you?

To answer the second question, the limit is meant in the sense of limits of sequences, just like in real analysis. To elaborate, remember that $K$ comes equipped with an absolute value $\left|-\right|_K : K\to \Bbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ which defines a topology on $K,$ with basis given by all open balls $B_\epsilon(x) := \{y\in K\mid |y - x|_K < \epsilon\},$ where $x$ ranges over all of $K$ and $\epsilon$ ranges over all positive reals.

Now, since $x_m, y_m\in K,$ it makes sense to consider the limit of the sequence $\{(x_m + y_m)^{p^m}\}_{m\geq 0}.$ This sequence converges to $\ell\in  K$ if, for every $\epsilon > 0,$ there exists $N > 0$ such that $|(x_m + y_m)^{p^m} - \ell|_K < \epsilon$ whenever $m\geq N.$

Comment: Thank you very much, I think I now get it and am not confused by the calculation. For instance, it can happen that $x_m + y_m$ has the same growth rate that $\ell^\frac{1} {p^m}$ for some $\ell$,  in which case the limit is clear. That's for $n=0$, and we do the same for all the other $n>0$, so that in the end we have a well defined element of $K^\flat$.